# iOS ARC block retain cycle

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, block, retain-cycle

Can someone confirm if the block below is turning into a retain cycle please? Please note the block is being called by SampleClass2 not SampleClass1.

```
@interface SampleClass1{
    NSArray *_array;
}

@implementation SampleClass1

-(void) doSomething {
    SampleClass2 *sampleClass2 = [[SampleClass2 alloc] init];
    [sampleClass2 doAnother:^(NSArray *anotherArray){
        _array = anotherArray;      // _array is an ivar
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: it's ok. As long as you don't retain block itself, you can use self inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Does the block retain `self`?* Yes.
- *Does `sampleClass2` retain the block?* Maybe. It depends on what the `doAnother:` method does. Without the code, it's impossible to say.
- *Even if we assume that `sampleClass2` retains the block, is there a retain cycle?* No. There is a connection `sampleClass2 -> the block -> self`, but nowhere from the code shown is there a connection from `self` to `sampleClass2`.

Answer (score 0):

There only can be a retain cycle when the block is kept around in an ivar or property. We don't see what `-[SampleClass2 doAnother:]` does with the block, so we don't know.

The block does capture `self` implicitly by referencing the ivar `_array`, so there's a chance that a reference cycle is formed. It depends on who retains the `SampleClass1` instance and what `SampleClass2` does with the block.

Comment: Whatever you do inside a block won't affect retain cycles outside a block. The only case of retain cycle is when you retain block itself, for example: [self block:^(id smth) {
        [self function]; Also how you can say "there is a chance" - either there is retain cycle or there's not :)
    }];

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski If the `doAnother:` method ends up retaining the block then there will be a reference cycle.

Comment: Not really - if SampleClass2 retains (copy) a block it will release it after object will be deallocated - and block itself is not retaining SampleClass2 in any place.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski That depends on the ownership graph as a whole. If the block is retained by `sampleClass2` and `sampleClass2` is retained by the `SampleClass1` instance there's a cycle.